# GAE redirect the user to oauth2 without loosing the information from the initial request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm using GAE with python. I'm working on an application that opens specific files from drive.

When you try to open a file from drive with your application, you are redirected to a url like this one :

http://my-app.appspot.com/state=%7B%22ids%22:%5B%220B1AXKdjZqM9FZDNIZEhMZEh0YzA%22%5D,%22action%22:%22open%22,%22userId%22:%22102709420614967238115%22%7D

In my program, I need to check if the application is authorized by the user; and to do so, I need it to be redirected to the oauth2 util it's authorized and then come back to the previous url.. or at least I need to efficiently save the information:

state=%7B%22ids%22:%5B%220B1AXKdjZqM9FZDNIZEhMZEh0YzA%22%5D,%22action%22:%22open%22,%22userId%22:%22102709420614967238115%22%7D

How can I redirect the user without loosing the information from the initial request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `state` parameter

```
state
```

> Any string    Provides any state that might be useful to your application
>   upon receipt of the response. The Google Authorization Server
>   roundtrips this parameter, so your application receives the same value
>   it sent. Possible uses include redirecting the user to the correct
>   resource in your site, nonces, and cross-site-request-forgery
>   mitigations.

Comment: When I use flow.state I get this error: 'OAuth2WebServerFlow' object has no attribute 'state'